# How do you make Python 2.7 the default version of Python for your Mac?

Tags: python, macos, path

This question has been asked many times but the answers are not sufficient for this specific problem. I am attempting to install Hyperledger and part of this relies on node-gyp and on terminal "node-gyp rebuild" is running.

I cannot find where this script is on my computer but it is trying to use Anaconda Python which is messing up the script due to a simple parenthesis error (2.7 print is of the form print 'hi' but then 3.x treats print more like a method).

So my question is how do I change the default Python version when scripts like these try to use Python on my system so they can use 2.7 the one that ships with Mac and not Anaconda and cause me problems.

Comment: run it with `/ful/path/to/python script`

Comment: I think the answer would be to change what is outputted when you put in the command "which python" - right now it's giving me /anaconda3/bin/python I need to change it to /usr/bin/python.... how do I do this?

Comment: on linux is command update-alternatives - it should be also on mac. More: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu

Comment: Well... I just fixed it. I forgot how though unfortunately. I hope someone comments on how to actually do it though to help everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pyenv:

```
pyenv global 2.7.9
```

[How to setup and use pyenv](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/)